# How to call another php/html page to print within window.print() function

Tags: php, html, css

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.print('index.php');
```

//How to call another php/html page to print within window.print() function

Answer (score 0):

In your index.php use `window.print()` and just call your index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //call here index.php
</script>
```